# Python / rq - monitoring worker status

Tags: python, task-queue

If this is an idiotic question, I apologize and will go hide my head in shame, but:

I'm using rq to queue jobs in Python. I want it to work like this:

1. Job A starts. Job A grabs data via web API and stores it.
2. Job A runs.
3. Job A completes.
4. Upon completion of A, job B starts. Job B checks each record stored by job A and adds some additional response data.
5. Upon completion of job B, user gets a happy e-mail saying their report's ready.

My code so far:

```
redis_conn = Redis()
use_connection(redis_conn)
q = Queue('normal', connection=redis_conn) # this is terrible, I know - fixing later
w = Worker(q)
job = q.enqueue(getlinksmod.lsGet, theURL,total,domainid)
w.work()
```

I assumed my best solution was to have 2 workers, one for job A and one for B. The job B worker could monitor job A and, when job A was done, get started on job B.

What I can't figure out to save my life is how I get one worker to monitor the status of another. I can grab the job ID from job A with job.id. I can grab the worker name with w.name. But haven't the foggiest as to how I pass any of that information to the other worker.

Or, is there a much simpler way to do this that I'm totally missing?

Comment: If job B cannot run until job A is complete (implying they cannot run in parallel), why use rq at all? Just do them sequentially (in a separate thread or process if you don't want to block your application)

Comment: The jobs for A and B each take a very long time, and can happen separately, so I'd like to be able to keep running lots of job A's independent of job B. If it's too difficult I may surrender, though.

Comment: Do you have pairs of A and B that go together, or can any B depend on any A? Because in the latter case you've got one hell of a syncronization problem. :-)

Comment: People always tell me that :)    Yes, they're paired, so ideally I'd match job id for A to a specific monitor in B. Again, this may simply be too complicated.

Comment: Then just combine the paired A and B in one job and save yourself a lot of trouble. :)

Comment: Sigh. Yeah, I'm getting there. That's what I'll probably have to do. Just have lots of workers available so we can run multiple jobs at once, and set a long timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably too deep into your project to switch, but if not, take a look at `Twisted`. http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ I am using it right now for a project that hits APIs, scrapes web content, etc. It runs multiple jobs in parallel, as well as organizing certain jobs in order, so Job B doesn't execute until Job A is done.

This is the best tutorial for learning Twisted if you want to attempt. http://krondo.com/?page_id=1327

Answer (score 7):

**Update januari 2015**, this pull request is now merged, and the parameter is renamed to `depends_on`, ie:

```
second_job = q.enqueue(email_customer, depends_on=first_job)
```

The original post left intact for people running older versions and such:

I have submitted a pull request (https://github.com/nvie/rq/pull/207) to handle job dependencies in RQ. When this pull request gets merged in, you'll be able to do:

```
def generate_report():
    pass

def email_customer():
    pass

first_job = q.enqueue(generate_report)
second_job = q.enqueue(email_customer, after=first_job)
# In the second enqueue call, job is created,
# but only moved into queue after first_job finishes
```

For now, I suggest writing a wrapper function to sequentially run your jobs. For example:

```
def generate_report():
     pass

def email_customer():
    pass

def generate_report_and_email():
    generate_report()
    email_customer() # You can also enqueue this function, if you really want to

# Somewhere else
q.enqueue(generate_report_and_email)
```

Answer (score 2):

From [this page](http://python-rq.org/docs/) on the `rq` docs, it looks like each `job` object has a `result` attribute, callable by `job.result`, which you can check.  If the job hasn't finished, it'll be `None`, but if you ensure that your job returns some value (even just `"Done"`), then you can have your other worker check the result of the first job and then begin working only when `job.result` has a value, meaning the first worker was completed.

Answer (score 0):

Combine the things that job A and job B do in one function, and then use e.g. `multiprocessing.Pool` (it's `map_async` method) to farm that out over different processes.

I'm not familiar with rq, but `multiprocessing` is a part of the standard library. By default it uses as many processes as your CPU has cores, which in my experience is usually enough to saturate the machine.